# Java ProcessBuilder issue

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am having trouble using the > operator to write to file in `Process Builder`. The actual process will run fine and let me parse using a `InputStreamReader` etc to parse the output. I want the process to be written to file using command line like >test.json for example.

**Here is my code**

```
try {
    //process builder used to run a Python script 
    ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder("python",
    System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\createJson.py","--structure","cloc.csv",
                                  "--weights","EntityEffort.csv",">","a.json");

    process.directory(new File("c:\\users\\chris\\desktop\\test2"));
    Process p = process.start();

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions or is the problem limited to not getting the output file?

Comment: Redirection symbols are interpreted by the command shell.  In Linux you would have to invoke a shell (i.e. bash) which then executes the command line. I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm unsure how this works in Windows (i.e. does cmd.exe get invoked under the covers here) but I suspect you need to invoke cmd.exe and pass it the command line you want to execute.

Answer (score 2):

As @JimGarrison points out, `>` is interpreted by the shell. Here you are directly starting a process for `createJson.py`, without a shell.

In UNIX you could use ProcessBuilder to start a shell using:

```
process = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "someCommand", ">", "outputfile");
```

Something similar will probably work with Windows and `cmd.exe`.

However, it's not very good practice. It's an opportunity for command injection attacks. Calling external processes is a last-resort approach, and you should try and minimise what you do within those processes.

So you would be better off sticking with what you have, and handle the redirect to file in Java. The ProcessBuilder javadoc gives an example:

```
File log = new File("log");
processBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
```